# Gesture detector on custom view

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I have defined a class that extends `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` and overrides the `onDown` and `onFling` methods

```
class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(PersianDatePicker.this.getContext(),
                "fling " + velocityX + " - " + velocityY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

And I also defined an instance of `GestureDetectorCompat`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I tested it in an activity and it works well. I want to use it in a customized view but it doesn't work! And I have no error.

Comment: you can check more info at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37136686

Comment: Engineering team has fixed this issue and corresponding document will be updated in future.

Answer (score 5):

In your custom view, try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }    

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

or, more tersely:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) || super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: If I am inside the `onTouch` method of `View.OnTouchListener()` that I set on a view (rather than subclassing the view), how do I call `super.onTouchEvent(event)` since `super` in that case would refer to the `OnTouchListener`?

Comment: @Suragch - So you have a pure `View` that you are using to implement some sort of touch response logic? You can either pass the view in to your touch listener as an injected value, from which it can then call the view's `onTouchEvent` or you can forgo all of that and handle the touch logic entirely within the listener. Which approach to adopt depends on what's appropriate for your application.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was asking. Thanks.

Comment: Engineering team has fixed this issue and corresponding document will be updated in future